# Selenium with postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, selenium-webdriver, quoted-identifier

I'm trying to connect Selenium with Postgres and the following error is shown:

> FAILED: selectQuery org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation
>   "login" does not exist

My code is below:

> ```
> package Posgress;
>
> import java.sql.Connection;
> import java.sql.DriverManager;
> import java.sql.ResultSet;
> import java.sql.SQLException;
> import java.sql.Statement;
> import org.testng.annotations.Test;
>
> @Test public class PosgressTest {
>   public static void selectQuery() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
>     //Load MySQL JDBC Driver
>     Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
>     Connection connection =
>       DriverManager
>         .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DIC","postgres", "root");
>
>     Statement st = connection.createStatement();
>     System.out.println("Connection");
>     String selectquery = "Select * from Login";
>     System.out.println("Connection1");
>
>     // Executing the SQL Query and store the results in ResultSet
>     ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(selectquery);
>
>     // While loop to iterate through all data and print results
>     while (rs.next()) {
>       System.out.println(rs.getString("username"));
>       System.out.println(rs.getString("password"));
>     }
>
>     // Closing DB Connection
>     connection.close();
>   }
> }
> ```

I have a table 'Login inside schema "DICschema'. I wrote select query like this also "Select * from DICschema.Login" then also same error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should rename the table to "login" and the schema to "dicschema", not "Login" and "DICschema". Because the query will ignore the case of text. 
The query will be like:
"Select * from dicschema.login"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your schema and table name as it is (not changing the character cases), the following query should work for you.

```
String selectquery = "SELECT * FROM \"DICschema\".\"Login\" ";
```

This is because when the string in compiled, it changes to lowercase and it can be avoided by using backslash.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that postgres users are unable to access the DIC schema.
Try to attach the prefix(schema) name to the query.

Comment: I have given like this also"Select * from DICschema.Login".Same error I got

Comment: Does the postgres user have access to the DICschema?

Comment: how to give previllages to access schema to the user?

Comment: but the table in public can be connected .